Infinite Generators of a Cone
Show that the cone ${3yz-2zx-2xy = 0}$ has infinite set of three mutually perpendicular generator
Here is what I have tried so far
Let three mutually perpendicular line have direction cosine's ($l_{1}$,$m_{1}$,$n_{1}$) , ($l_{2}$,$m_{2}$,$n_{2}$) , ($l_{3}$,$m_{3}$,$n_{3}$)
Now I am only able to prove that if two of these lines( let ($l_{1}$,$m_{1}$,$n_{1}$) , ($l_{2}$,$m_{2}$,$n_{2}$) ) are generator of cone: ${fyz+gzx+hxy = 0}$. It will pass through the third line as well.
D.c's satisfies the cone equation
${fm_{1}n_{1} + gn_{1}l_{1} + hl_{1}m_{1} = 0}$
${fm_{2}n_{2} + gn_{2}l_{2} + hl_{2}m_{2} = 0}$
Adding above equations
${f(m_{1}n_{1} + m_{2}n_{2}) + g(n_{1}l_{1} + n_{2}l_{2}) + h(l_{1}m_{1} + l_{2}m_{2}) = 0}$
Since three lines taken are perpendicular (${m_{1}n_{1} + m_{2}n_{2} + m_{3}n_{3} = 0}$ , ${n_{1}l_{1} + n_{2}l_{2} + n_{3}l_{3} = 0}$ , ${l_{1}m_{1} + l_{2}m_{2} + l_{3}m_{3} = 0}$)
This gives
${-fm_{3}n_{3} - gn_{3}l_{3} - hl_{3}m_{3} = 0}$
or
${fm_{3}n_{3} + gn_{3}l_{3} + hl_{3}m_{3} = 0}$
How do I now prove that there exist infinite set of two perpendicular generator (my initial assumption) ?
Please also suggest if there is another method to do the same.

Probably the equation should be $3−2x−2=0$.

@Intelligentipauca thanks for pointing out.
